# Ingresar punto decimal en un edittext

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema , en una app de una calculadora en android studio , sencilla , tengo 2 `EditText` y que introduzca números de `phone(InputType="Phone")` , por mas que he intentado no se como limitar a que solo se pueda introducir un punto decimal

De antemano muchas gracias.

Lo que he intentado :

```
switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.suma:
        String aux1=numero1.getText().toString();
        String aux2=numero2.getText().toString();
        String rta="";
        float result = 0;
        if (numero1.getText().toString().contains(".")){

            rta="Tiene un punto";
            resultado1.setText("Hey"+ rta);
        break;}
        else {
            float numero1 = Float.parseFloat(aux1);
            float numero2 = Float.parseFloat(aux2);
            result = numero1 + numero2;
            resultado1.setText("tu" + result);
            break;
}
```

1. Elemento de lista

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir algo más de código? Es que me falta algo de información para entender la lógica que has seguido.
Veo que compruebas que el primer sumando tenga un punto, pero no compruebas cuántos tiene. Además te faltaría comprobar el segundo sumando. 
Quizás una opción es hacer un controlador cuando escriban los valores y no comprobarlo cuando se efectúa la suma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo entendido que el mismo InputType=Phone te provee la opción para hacer eso, no necesitas programar algo más para ello, también intenta poner esto en el XML del EditTexto:

```
android:digits="1234567890.-"
```

Intenta con eso y me avisas que pasa...

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Ya tenía ingresado los datos del digits , utilicé un try catch 

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso yo utilicé el siguiente fragmento

```
if (variable.indexOf('.') != -1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ya se ha agregado un punto decimal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```